# Cannot find module 'lodash.curry' via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am working on **Currying** topic from [Mostly Adequate Guide by Professor Frisby](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch4.html), I try to install lodash via `npm` after realize browser can't run `require()`.  I've been through searching here to use similar solutions but doesn't work, I want to make it run on Node on local server or using `script`, still same results below and also `ramda`.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.curry'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hueke32/Desktop/lodash_test/lodashTest.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:431:10)
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "lodash_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lodashTest.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

lodashTest.js

```
var curry = require('lodash.curry');

var match = curry(function(what, str) {
  return str.match(what);
});

var replace = curry(function(what, replacement, str) {
  return str.replace(what, replacement);
});

var filter = curry(function(f, ary) {
  return ary.filter(f);
});

var map = curry(function(f, ary) {
  return ary.map(f);
});

match(/\s+/g, "hello world");

match(/\s+/g)("hello world");

var hasSpaces = match(/\s+/g);

hasSpaces("hello world");

hasSpaces("spaceless");

filter(hasSpaces, ["tori_spelling", "tori amos"]);

var findSpaces = filter(hasSpaces);

findSpaces(["tori_spelling", "tori amos"]);

var noVowels = replace(/[aeiou]/ig);

var censored = noVowels("*");

censored("Chocolate Rain");
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="lodashTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to use the `lodash.curry` module, you have to install it, not `lodash`.

Comment: Great book, I am working my way through it now. @FelixKling is correct, `npm install lodash.curry` and then `require('lodash.curry')` will work.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, you are right.  Perfect, it is working now, according to the book, it says to use `npm install lodash`.  I see that it is different lodash that has curry, I can't wait to work on it.  Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

`lodash.curry` is not a module. `lodash` is a module with `curry` as a member. You should correct your require like below.

`var curry = require('lodash').curry;`

Comment: [`lodash.curry`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.curry) certainly _is_ a module.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I thought it was only one lodash that has all modules available, in the future I will make sure to use fully `require('lodash.curry'), yes your example is working well too.

Comment: @thunderRX5 there is both a "full" `lodash`, and separate modules for most (all?) commands. The difference is that the full version is rather large, which might be a bit of a waste (esp when using client side) if you only use a few commands. In that case, including the separate command modules will save space.